# Why does my session-based login system not work?

Tags: php, session

I have just started learning PHP, and I wrote an account system with PHP and mySQL for my website.  I know the sql stuff is working fine, the problem is my PHP session.

When I go to test it, I can try to login, and it fails.  Then, I try to login again, and it will succeed.  It always succeeds on the second attempt to login.  It never succeeds on the first attempt in Firefox, but it does in Chrome.  Also, a couple of times in Chrome, after I succeeded in logging in, going to a some different pages on my site seemed to erase the session.  Or, at least, that session was not registering on those other pages.  I didn't have that problem on Firefox.  I have checked, double-checked, and triple-checked, and all of my pages call session_start() before anything else, so I know that can't be the problem.

I must not have a full enough understanding of PHP sessions, as it's just not working consistently.

After posting this, I tested in IE, and everything works fine there.  I log in on the first attempt, and any page I visit maintains my session.

Here is the code for the php script that actually "logs in" the user:

```
<?php
session_start();
//pass info to mysql(servername, username, password)
$connect = mysql_connect ("localhost", "ggstudio", "mtgertai1");
if (!$connect) 
{
    die ('Failed to connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("ggstudio_accountDatabase", $connect);

//capture data sent to page through login
//usernameField and passwordField

$usernameSubmission = $_POST[usernameField];
$passwordSubmission = $_POST[passwordField];

$validAccount = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userAccounts WHERE userID = '$usernameSubmission' AND userPassword = '$passwordSubmission'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($validAccount);
if (($row['userID'] == $usernameSubmission)&&($row['userPassword'] == $passwordSubmission))
{
/*********************************
**********************************
assign global variables to session
after starting session and then***
redirect to user homepage*********
**********************************
**********************************
*/
//get account number from database
$_SESSION['accountNumber']= $row['accountNumber'];
//get first name from database
$_SESSION['firstName']= $row['firstName'];
//get last name from database
$_SESSION['lastName']= $row['lastName'];
//save username into session
$_SESSION['username']= $row['userID'];
//save password into session (only really useful if user wants to change password)
$_SESSION['userPassword']= $row['userPassword'];
//get user's email address from database
$_SESSION['userEmail']= $row['userEmail'];
//get GP from database
$_SESSION['gpoints']= $row['userGloryPoints'];
//get user join date from database
$_SESSION['userJoinDate']= $row['userJoinDate'];
//get user rank
$_SESSION['userRank']= $row['userRank'];

header('Location: http://www.glorygamer.com/account_home.php');
}
else
{
    $loginFailed= TRUE;
    setcookie("incorrectLogin", $loginFailed, time()+20);
    header('Location: http://www.glorygamer.com/shibboleth.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: The PHP code that handles logins is going to be needed to help you here...

Comment: Post your sample code so we can help you with your problem.

Comment: Thank you.  I wasn't sure if there was some obvious known issue that would be evident if I described it without the code.  I have included the code in my original question now.

Comment: What is you current session configuration? And how do you check the login state on the other pages?

Comment: And please read on [SQL Injections](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) as your script is currently vulnerable to it.

Comment: I check the login state on other pages by using isset() with one of the session array elements.

Also, I do not know what my "session configurations" are.  I do not know what this entails.  As I said, I am new to PHP, so a lot of this isn't familiar territory to me.  I even find the syntax fairly far off from languages that I am proficient in.

Comment: @rbusch90: You can read [the session configuration options on this manual page](http://php.net/session.configuration).

Comment: Thanks.  My options seem to all be at the default (which seems plausable, as I have never changed them myself).

Answer (score 2):

If the session is working intermittently then I'd say there's one of two things happening:

- Your session isn't being set in the browser correctly
- Your session isn't being saved on the server in time.

One thing that can happen (especially when you're testing on localhost) is that an authenticated session isn't written to disk in time for the next request, hence the next request appears to be un-authenticated (remember that apache is multi-process; your second request could be handled by another process which isn't aware of what the first is doing).  Here's one possible solution:

```
$_SESSION['userRank']= $row['userRank'];
session_write_close();
header('Location: http://www.glorygamer.com/account_home.php');
```

The call to `session_write_close()` should mean that your authenticated session is ready in time for the next request.

HTH.

Comment: Thank you, THANK YOU!  That fixed the problem of not logging in on my first attempt.  However, it still seems to lose the session sometimes if I go to the "wrong page".  Again, this page is on the same server, and it calls session_start() as it is supposed to...

Comment: Should I be calling session_write_close() somewhere on every page?

Comment: I stand corrected.  That fixed the problem of having to log in twice on FireFox... Chrome still has this problem sometimes.  Also, the page I go to on my site that "ends the session" does not always do that, either.  It seems to happen intermittently.

Comment: @rbusch90: I would call `session_write_close` immediately before and `exit` immediately after each `header` redirection. The former writes the `$_SESSION` data to the storage and the latter avoids further code being executed.

Comment: I don't think I have any other header redirections, except for the one in this script.  Most of the other site navigation is html links.

Comment: If this means anything: when I look at the php.ini and change the output buffering to 'on', it seems like the pages that used to load the session correctly before no longer do.  Additionally, the pages that did not load correctly before now load correctly.  Odd.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I see are the lack of single quotes.  Also, you should definitely escape these so that nobody can do any SQL injection on you.

```
$usernameSubmission = $_POST[usernameField];
$passwordSubmission = $_POST[passwordField];
```

should be:

```
$usernameSubmission = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usernameField']);
$passwordSubmission = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['passwordField']);
```

Comment: This is definitely not the cause of this problem.

Comment: This didn't fix my problem, but patching up holes in security is priceless, nonetheless.  Thank you for that bit of help.